# Owl Carousel - Slide orders, skip straight to selected slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have an issue on a client site as I have replaced a old poorly supported carousel plugin with the much more shiny and supported Owl Carousel. On the whole I have found Owl to be much better in almost all respects however there is a minor difference in the way they work that the client isn't happy with.

On the existing image carousel showing one image you can skip forward and back through the images (1-5) by clicking the number of the slide. When a slide number is clicked the slide changes straight to the selected slide, so even if skipping from slide 1 to slide 5 you will only ever see 5 come straight over 1 as can be seen below:
http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_1.htm

Owl on the other hand works differently, the same scenario as above however when skipping from the first to the last slide you will always see the slides in between flash by as can be seen in the ling below:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

I would ideally like functionality of the first carousel on Owl if this is possible as it seems to offer a far better user XP in this respect. If anyone know how to do this an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try do it using custom events that owl carusel gives. 
For your case it is: "owl.jumpTo" //jumpTo provided item. Without slide animation.
You can find more information [at their website](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing)